outlook display recipient domain
I have a few simple code working good in outlook VBA editor, prompting domains of recipient.
I want to make it a installable to share with teammates. No easy way other than making it a  addin.
Following steps from Internet, when adding reference for my project in VS, I can't find "MS outlook..." so I used "MS office..." instead. No idea why, I installed everything needed.
I also got error saying can't debug because needed outlook version not installed. No matter outlook is running or closed.
But I was able to build and publish the code, with below file structure:
│  RecipientDomainCheck.vsto
│  setup.exe
│
└─Application Files
    └─RecipientDomainCheck_1_0_0_1
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll.deploy
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.dll.deploy
            RecipientDomainCheck.dll.deploy
            RecipientDomainCheck.dll.manifest
            RecipientDomainCheck.vsto

I installed it successfully. But not working at all. Below is version info and the code.
Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.9.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.9.5+34723.18
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.9.199.22661
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure application service tool 3.0.0    17.9.199.22661
Azure application service tool 3.0.0 

C# tool   4.9.0-3.24121.1+a98c90d56455379836dd5c845b35fa932b00cfa3

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet package manager   6.9.2

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.9.2.2412004+684740676513b3b208d5bd5b7f8786dab8d287b7

SQL Server Data Tools   17.9.55.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   17.0.30103.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic tool   4.9.0-3.24121.1+a98c90d56455379836dd5c845b35fa932b00cfa3

Visual F# Tools   17.9.0-beta.23614.3+a521e1cd420beb56c15faf6836184fadd2b7937a
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2

Visual Studio Office developer tool   17.6.34328.02

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Code in "ThisAddin.vb"(was displaying domains but to make troubleshooting simple I modified only display a msg box):
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub


    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

        If MsgBox("The email contains external domains", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Domains") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub


End Class


